# Why does not work filter with track by $index?

Tags: angularjs

There is unput field on page:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchInside">
```

Also `ng-repeat` below:

```
ng-repeat="item in details track by $index | filter:searchInside"
```

When I insert symbols in input filter `searchInside` does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because filters should be applied before the `track by` expression.
So, move `track by $index` to the end:

```
item in details | filter:searchInside track by $index
```

Comment: It works, but when I typing text `ng-repeat` shows empty result, but  `{{details.length}}` is equal 1 still, why?

Comment: it is hard to say w/o input params, maybe you're trying to apply filter that don't match your details data, here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/d33eaz5q/

Comment: Look, problem is same: https://jsfiddle.net/d33eaz5q/1/ Always four items in details after filtering

Comment: ok, this is normal behavior because `filter` not modifies original array, but you can assign filtered array to new variable, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/d33eaz5q/3/

Comment: Thanks, will know about it